# How to wait for first async await method before continuing second method in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, timer, async-await

I created two method in mvc c# using **async** **task** **await** for first action method I use following code

```
Thread sendData = new Thread(async () => await SaveCustomerDataAsync(DocumentID, DocumentType, bytes, fileName));
sendData.Start();
```

Now on my submit click this method runs in background and take some time to save in database with flag set to 1 on other-hand for next page which is kind of form submit I again use

```
int Flag = await repository.GetFlagStatus(DocumentID);
```

and for getting flag status form database table I use

```
public int GetFlagStatus(string documentID)
        {          
            var obj = (from a in db.StdPortals
                             select new StdPortalsVM
                             {
                                 DocumentID = a.DocumentID,
                                 Flag = a.Flag,
                             }).Where(x => x.DocumentID == documentID).FirstOrDefault();
          var  result = Convert.ToInt32(obj.Flag);
            return result;
        }
```

Now my question is that how to wait for second method until my first method save data in database as flag 0 or flag 1 according to out put of first method.
I used await Task.Delay(10000); to await second method but why should i wait for 10s if data save in database before 10s user will wait for it.

So, to remove that part I use timer to check database table row update after 5 sec and I modify my code like this

```
System.Threading.Timer Timer;
        System.DateTime StopTime;       
        public void Run(string documentId)
        {
            StopTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
            Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, documentId, 0, 5000);      
        }
        private void TimerCallback(object state)
        {           
            if (System.DateTime.Now >= StopTime)
            {
                Timer.Dispose();
                return;              
            }
            else
            {
               var obj = (from a in db.StdPortals
                             select new StdPortalsVM
                             {
                                 DocumentID = a.DocumentID,
                                 Flag = a.Flag,
                             }).Where(x => x.DocumentID == documentID).FirstOrDefault();          
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Timer.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
            }           
        }
```

So for this I am getting following error 
I also use this method to check table but getting same error.

```
bool obj = db.StdPortals.Any(u => u.DocumentID == state.ToString())
```

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'*

I hope you understand my queries that how to wait in async task or how to check database after 5 second.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better question, why does it take so long to save data? You might want to address your current bottleneck before engineering around it.

Comment: Instead of a timer on a separate thread, you can also use a loop with a Task.Delay of 1 or 2 seconds. Loop until you get a value.

Comment: @gunr2171 Better question, why does it take so long to save data? see because I use one webservice to send parameter and get response that response takes some time like 20sec-30sec or less and that response was save in database and with that response I need to load other view.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing can you give me some code regarding delay in loop because I already use await Task.Delay(10000); it wait for 10s but why should i use that. I want to wait until get response not more not fixed.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve. But a DbContext cannot be shared between threads. And  you should not use Thread or Timer in an mvc app.

Comment: @HenkHolterman why should not use thread or timer in mvc? please read my upper comments

Comment: Are you able to do this without using the ThreadStart?  If you're just using Task, you could then just wait for it till it's ready.

Comment: @benmartin101 I dont want to wait for response I want to load in background. and check response in 2nd action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thread sendData = new Thread(async () => await SaveCustomerDataAsync(DocumentID, DocumentType, bytes, fileName));
>   sendData.Start();

You shouldn't use `Thread` in modern code; the only remaining use case for `Thread` is COM interop, which you're not doing here. Use `Task` instead:

```
Task sendData = Task.Run(async () => await SaveCustomerDataAsync(DocumentID, DocumentType, bytes, fileName));
```

In addition to being smaller code, the `Task` has much nicer ways to detect completion and exceptions.

For example, if you want to asynchronously wait for `sendData` to complete, you can just `await` it:

```
await sendData;
// SaveCustomerDataAsync has completed now.
```

Comment: I modify my code like you said but I don't want to wait until my first call send response. I want them load in background because I want to load another view in which I have one form,so when I received data from first call I will combine that two data and show them into third view.

Comment: You don't have to `await` it right away. Just save the `Task` somewhere and `await` it when you need the response.

Comment: Stephen I marked your answer and listen your advice I used do...while loop to hold for first response and when I got first response I merge that response with second one. So thanks for help:)